# How can I run an Entity Framework 7 migration on a remote database using Powershell?

Tags: entity-framework, powershell, visual-studio-2015

In a standalone entity framework 7 project (note, not a MVC project with an entity context where the command DNX might be used), how can I run a migration on a remote database using Powershell?

I am currently using Entity Framework 7.0.0-rc1-final with Visual Studio 2015 (14.0.23107.0).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the moment there is no way you can use pure PowerShell to do this because a utility like migrate.exe does not exist yet and importing the EF PS modules is not possible as they require a Package Manager PowerShell Host.

Here are some ideas how you can update a remote db in EF7:

One thing you could do is use the package manager console commands from within VS as usual to update the remote db. You can create a second context that has the remote db connection string and use the update-database command specifying the context to use. These commands require the following package in EF7:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Commands/. 
I have done this successfully in a class lib project.

Another solution would be to use DNX commands by creating a DNX project instead of a classic one. DNX projects are not just for web sites, it is just another type of project. Here is a link that shows how to create a console app DNX project:
http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/console.html.
So with this type of project you can use the provided DNX commands that you seem to be aware of.

I hope this helped. Maybe we can give more help if you describe your situation and your end goal in more detail.

Comment: **At the moment there is no way you can use pure PowerShell to do this because a utility like migrate.exe does not exist yet and importing the EF PS modules is not possible as they require a Package Manager PowerShell Host.** This is good to know; I didn't realize that the EF PS commands weren't usable outside of the VS Package Manager PS Host.

Comment: **One thing you could do is use the package manager console commands from within VS as usual to update the remote db. You can create a second context that has the remote db connection string and use the update-database commend specifying the context to use. These commands require the following package in EF7: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Commands/. I have done this successfully in a class lib project.**  I'll try going down this route as I think this would accomplish my goal of being able to target individual remote databases with different credential schemes using powershell

Comment: @StampyTurtle I am happy this idea is of help.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty :)

Answer (score 1):

Answer too long as a comment, so adding it here...

Have you looked at this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238640/how-to-run-code-first-migrations-from-a-psake-build) and the links in the answer?

> *From that answer*
>
> The problem with importing the module into a PowerShell console is that I believe the module expects to run in a context where it has a Visual Studio DTE object available. That environment is the NuGet Package Manager Console. This issue has been brought up before. Check out this [blog post](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/05/thoughts-on-installing-and-updating.html) and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386672/using-nuget-to-update-project-files-outside-of-package-manager-console).
>
> This [blog post shows how to write code that does migrations.](http://romiller.com/2012/02/09/running-scripting-migrations-from-code/)

What might be helpful for readers of this question is what you have tried, what is not working, and other information that might help solve your problem.